# List conversion/transformation

Tags: python, list

Any way to transform list_1 into list_2?:

```
list_1 = [('h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'), ('w', 'o', 'r', 'd')]

list_2 = ['hello', 'word']
```

Comment: What did you try? Did you read the documentation of the [methods of strings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)?

Comment: As @Bakuriu says, you should try before asking, and post in your question what have you tried to solve the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the data.

```
data = [('h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'), ('w', 'o', 'r', 'd')]
```

Let's start with the basics. We just try to work on one tuple. The following loop will print out every single string in the tuple.

```
element = ('h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o')
for character in element:
    print(character)
```

Looking at the output we can see a simple way to create a combined string. Just declare an empty string at the beginning, then add all the characters to it.

```
word = ''
for character in element:
    word = word + character
print(word)
```

The result looks good, but there is an better way to do it. Strings have a [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join) method we can use here.

```
print(''.join(element))
```

You get the same result as with the loop before: `'hello'`.

Now we have to expand our code to use all the tuples in our data. Just add another loop on the outside.

```
for element in data:
    print(''.join(element))
```

To create a new list we use a pattern we used before when we built a string. We create an empty list before the loop and add the results of the `join` to it.

```
result = []
for element in data:
    result.append(''.join(element))
print(result)
```

Code like this calls for a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
result = [''.join(element) for element in data]
print(result)
```

That's all.

Comment: Thank you. I just felt the urgent need to explain how you can start to solve problems like this.

Answer (score 4):

```
list_2 = [''.join(word) for word in list_1]
```